# Why my physics bodies pass through each other after a few collisions in spritekit?

Tags: sprite-kit

I am working on a game which involves a character jumping on plateforms like the Doodle jump game. The problem is the character will pass through the plateform after a few collisions with it. For jumping i use `restitution`
`player.physicsbody.restitution = 1.0` 
I apply force to the physicbody of character based on accelerometer data in `update:` method.

Comment: Post the code that shows what you do to detect collision and what you do to the body after the collision. Be sure not to move physics nodes with move actions or by manually setting the position.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use;

```
sprite.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
```

[It is explained](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html) such as:

A small body might move so fast that it completely passes through another physics body without ever having a frame of animation where the two touch each other. If you have physics bodies that must collide, you can hint to Sprite Kit to use a more precise collision model to check for interactions.

Comment: Unfortunately, even setting that property may not fix the issue. I'm still having problems with fast-moving bodies passing through each other. There seems to be no guaranteed solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Hey man I had the same problem.

I had two limit nodes that were essentially bars that didn't move (isDynamic = false). I placed a moving bar between them and if I applied enough impulse, the bar would go through the limiting bars. I doubled the size of the limit bars so instead of being just 4 points tall they were 8 points tall.

After applying impulses way quicker than before, it seems the extra size made it possible for the computer to keep up and prevent the moving bar from passing through the limit bars.

\

OH. I also had to use the precise detection as well.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe provide a code example?

Comment: Yeah... 

After changing this...

        `limitNode1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 4))`


...to this...
`
        `limitNode1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 40))`

...my nodes stopped passing through each other. 

All of the movement was in the Y direction... so I suspect that the extra area in the Y axis of the limitNode was the solution.

I also see how this might not work in some scenarios... like if the sprite can't be changed due to aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Please edit it into your answer. Remember, you're not helping me, but future visitors. ;)